# Encrypt with Javascript library SJCL, decrypt with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptography

I am using this library: https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl

I want to encrypt a string client side, pass it through the URL, and then decrypt it in the backend.

This is the JS:

```
<script src="https://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/sjcl.js"></script>
<script>
var ciphertext = sjcl.encrypt("password", "Hello World!")
var plaintext = sjcl.decrypt("password", ciphertext)
console.log(ciphertext)
console.log(plaintext)
</script>
```

Results.

**console.log(plaintext)**:

```
{"iv":"XA+HFebsM7WiVy0Ko8EEuA==","v":1,"iter":1000,"ks":128,"ts":64,"mode":"ccm","adata":"","cipher":"aes","salt":"f4BX8a9fUPM=","ct":"a4LesnrsT7C6MmkxZifSw7FsDyI="}
```

**console.log(ciphertext)**:

```
Hello World!
```

As you can see, encryption and decryption work as intended with JS. The problem comes when I try to decrypt it using PHP:

```
$password = 'password';
$input    = json_decode('{"iv":"XA+HFebsM7WiVy0Ko8EEuA==","v":1,"iter":1000,"ks":128,"ts":64,"mode":"ccm","adata":"","cipher":"aes","salt":"f4BX8a9fUPM=","ct":"a4LesnrsT7C6MmkxZifSw7FsDyI="}', true);
$digest   = hash_pbkdf2('sha256', $password, base64_decode($input['salt']), $input['iter'], 16, true);
$cipher   = $input['cipher'] . '-' . $input['ks'] . '-' . $input['mode'];
$ct       = substr(base64_decode($input['ct']), 0, - $input['ts'] / 8);
$tag      = substr(base64_decode($input['ct']), - $input['ts'] / 8);
$iv       = base64_decode($input['iv']);
$adata    = $input['adata'];

$dt = openssl_decrypt($ct, $cipher, $digest, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag, $adata);
var_dump($dt);
while ($msg = openssl_error_string()) {
    echo $msg . "\n";
}
```

Result of `var_dump($dt)` is `false`, which is what happens when the `openssl_decrypt` fails to decrypt the string.
Surely I'm missing something, anyone could help me notice what it is?

Comment: PHP doesn't support CCM mode out of the box.

Comment: If you're using only symmetric encryption you need the exact same key at the server and the client. If you send the encryption key from the server to the client or the other way around you need to encrypt your symmetric encryption key. The easiest way to do this would be to use TLS. If you use TLS, then the data as well as key are encrypted, so you don't need to encrypt it yourself. This doesn't provide any security, just a little bit of obfuscation. You should read: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 3):

I've got it running when using mode 'gcm' with a 128-bit iv.

```
  var key = 'password';
  var p = { mode: 'gcm', iv: sjcl.random.randomWords(4, 0) };
  var encrypted = sjcl.encrypt(key, 'Hello World', p);
```

This leads to output e.g.:

```
{"iv":"/Jyo0DNWt0CNUW6AYkpnBw==","v":1,"iter":10000,"ks":128,"ts":64,"mode":"gcm","adata":"","cipher":"aes","salt":"jFSuZEEICq8=","ct":"7+M0Wv79zKXu4SUYJPZAIIBYgw=="}
```

This JSON output is used as input in PHP:

```
$input = json_decode('<JSON output from above goes here>', true);
```

which can be passed to decryption like mentioned in the example code above:

```
$password = 'password';
$digest   = hash_pbkdf2('sha256', $password, base64_decode($input['salt']), 
$input['iter'], 0, true);
$cipher   = $input['cipher'] . '-' . $input['ks'] . '-' . $input['mode'];
$ct       = substr(base64_decode($input['ct']), 0, - $input['ts'] / 8);
$tag      = substr(base64_decode($input['ct']), - $input['ts'] / 8);
$iv       = base64_decode($input['iv']);
$adata    = $input['adata'];

$dt = openssl_decrypt($ct, $cipher, $digest, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag, $adata);
var_dump($dt);
```

This worked for me using PHP version 7.1.9